# What does this elixir compiler error mean when running this exercism exercise?

Tags: elixir

New to elixir and I tried running the ["bob" exercise from exercism](https://github.com/ianstarz/exercism-elixir-bob) and received the following error when typing "elixir bob_test.exs" on the console:

> ** (ExUnit.DocTest.Error) could not retrieve the documentation for module Teenager. The module was not compiled with documentation or its beam file cannot be accessed
>       (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/doc_test.ex:378: ExUnit.DocTest.extract/1
>       (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/doc_test.ex:202: ExUnit.DocTest.**doctests**/2
>       bob_test.exs:6: (module)

Based on some preliminary research, I gather that the latest Elixir I'm using (1.1.1), I need to generate a beam file.  What is a beam file and how do I generate this?  And will this solve the issue of letting me run exercism elixir test exercises?

Comment: Did you make any changes to the bob_test.exs file? I just cloned the repo, ran `elixir bob_test.exs` and got 14 passing tests with no compiler errors. I'm also running Elixir 1.1.1 -- btw, .beam files are Elixir/Erlang compiled modules to Erlang VM bytecode

Comment: As it turns out, I was using an outdated version of "bob" from the elixir kata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elixir stores documentation in the bytecode and, when using script files, the bytecode is loaded directly in memory without writing to disk, so the documentation is unreachable.

The easiest and best way to solve the problem is to use mix:

```
$ mix new bob
```

It will create a project. Put your source code in "lib/bob.ex", your tests in "test/bob_test.exs" and running `mix test` will take care of the rest.

If you really don't want to use mix, you can use `elixirc bob.ex` to compile the file and generate the bytecode (you will see a `.beam` in your current directory). Then `elixir bob_test.exs` to run the test. Notice one is `elixirc` (c for compiler with ex extension) and the other is the regular elixir executable (with the exs extension, for scripts).